# Where does SharePoint 2003 store actual farm database configuration?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Migrating a 2003 SharePoint farm from an old SQL Server 2005 install to a SQL Server 2012 install on a separate server.

We recently lost our SharePoint expert, so since me the DBA uses Microsoft products it shouldn't be that much of a leap right?

I can't for the life of me find the actual farm database configuration in SharePoint. I will need to change the connection string(if it uses such a thing) to point to my new database server after I detach and attach the database files.

Comment: This is not a supported operation see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priyo/archive/2006/03/24/559896.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to move the content databases over, and then re-run the SharePoint Technologies Wizard and create a new config database. Once done you can recreate the applications and re-add the content databases. I have had to do this after upgrades / failed patches, config corruptions etc. With an upgrade, you will also want to run the tool again to update the database schemas to the latest version.